# Flash As3 Number of people online

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have created a Jar that I want to fill with fireflies, depending on how many users are online.

I did a little digging and I found how to create a XMLSocket. It worked but I didn't know how to get the information how many people are online and also it required a CMD window to run all the time.

The second way I found was trough a PHP,MYSQL witch I have runing with my Apache server, but the tutorials and scripts I found did not work for me, for [example](http://www.shaddeen.com/posts/read/id-1326397267). I did not create the required tables.

My question is what is the simplest way to find the current count of users online on your page/flash file? Is there a quick way to do it inside flash and not get involved with MYSQL or PHP?

Comment: Did you expect the example to work without creating the required tables?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a simple way to only do it in Flash without using any external part (PHP, MySQL, Java, and more...). Remember that Flash is run locally, and thus needs to interact with PHP or similar to interact with the server to tell the server about the activity by the user and to ask the server about other users activities (number of users online).

If you only want to display the users online, I recommend the way that is shown in the example you posted. Simply update the database when activity has been seen by a user and count the user as offline when no activity has been seen for x minutes. There's no need to involve XMLSockets for this unless you want the users to interact with each other in any way.

If you want more than just displaying the users online, I recommend using XMLSockets in ActionScript and looking into PHP Sockets.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think so, the flash player must need a way to "check" on the server the number of users who are online. the simplest would be to send a URLRequest (i hope i got the class name right) to a server script, which could be either a php or an aspx (or any server technology) script / page.

that server script should return the number of users the site has.

e.g.

```
var numberOfVisitors:Int = 0;

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    numberOfVisitors = e.target.data;

    // now print this 'numberOfVisitors' where you want to on the client
}

var numVisitors:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
numVisitors.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
numVisitors.load(new URLRequest("num_users.php"));
```

the next part would be a php script (or any other server script) that keeps track of the number of users. that i think you should post as another SO question perhaps?

Comment: I got the PHP script to work, but I cant access the variables form my PHP file

let's say I have a var in PHP '$Cake = "lie"' how can I access it from as3, when i use your example and then e.target.data.Cake it gives me an error 'Property not found on String and there is no default value.'

Comment: @Simeon you need to `echo` the result in PHP. Also make sure you use the correct setting on dataFormat: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#dataFormat (it should be the default, text, in your case). Then you use just the data-property of the URLLoader to access the string.

Comment: Simeon, i dont think you need to do e.target.data.Cake.. as Simon Andre suggested, just echo the output from the php script (<?php echo $Cake; ?>) and the e.target.data will catch it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, but I hat to link the php file not trough it's HTTP address, instead just the path relative to the .swf file (just myFile.php or path/myFile.php).

```
AS3 file:

NewRequest = new URLRequest("numOnline.php");
var numberOfVisitors:int = 10;
var NewRequest:URLRequest;
var UrlLoader:URLLoader;

UrlLoader = new URLLoader();
UrlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
UrlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
UrlLoader.load(NewRequest);


function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    trace(e.target.data);
    numberOfVisitors = int(e.target.data);
}
```

I convert the text As3 receives to int, because i don't know yet how to send veria

[php files](http://www.shaddeen.com/posts/read/id-1326397267)

```
main PHP file (the file that as3 connects to):

<?php
include_once 'config.php'; //This file would contain the variables needed to connect to the database with $link, below
include_once 'functions.php'; //We include the functions we have created

$database = "online";

$link = mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass)or die ("Could not connect to mysql because ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database)or die ("Could not select database because ".mysql_error());

usersOnline(5); //We call the usersOnline function with a time span of 5 minutes

showUsersOnline(1); //Show the number of users online, and the list of users

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

the function file sends the number of Visiters Online with `echo $count;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it without a database (MYSQL) and PHP; BUT you will still need a (Media) Server. 
I wouldn't suggest the following if your "only" purpose is to count the connecting clients, but if you have the reasons and have access to a **Flash Media Server**, you can try the following:

**On Server Side:**

1. Create an application (folder) on FMS, create the main.asc file inside that folder.
2. Inside the main.asc; create a (remote) [SharedObject (server-side)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/ssaslr/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7e63SSASLR.html) (e.g.: `users_so`)
3. Watch for connecting clients on `application.onConnect` event. Add each connecting client to that SharedObject inside this handler.
4. Also watch for disconnecting clients on `application.onDisconnect` event. Remove each disconnecting  client from the SharedObject inside this handler.

**On Client Side:**

1. Connect each Flash client to FMS (with your new app-folder path in the URI) when the application loads in the browser.
2. Watch for the `NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS` event and `"NetConnection.Connect.Success"` code. When connected; create a [SharedObject (client-side)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) and get the remote from the server.
3. Add the `SyncEvent.SYNC` event listener to the `SharedObject`. This will sync with each Flash client when a user connects or disconnects from the server.
4. Inside the sync event handler, get and count the users from the event response.
5. Display the count on your Flash client.

See [Server-Side ActionScript Language Reference for Flash Media Server 4.5](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/ssaslr/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7edfSSASLR.html), especially the **Application Class**.
Also useful: [Flash Media Server Developer Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver.html)

Hope this helps.